# change max quota WCF duplex?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm having an issue with quota when I try to get the content of a file through my web service. I'm using windows services to start and maintenant the connection.

Here below is the message I get:

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: 'Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'GetFileContent'. The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.'

Here my config files:

Server WCF web.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="behavior.ShipperServiceEndPointBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="behavior" name="MonitoringServer.MonitoringService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="tcpbinding"
          contract="MonitoringServer.IMonitoringService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:54322/Monitoring" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="tcpbinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The server Windows service app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
         </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="behavior.ShipperServiceEndPointBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="MonitoringServer.MonitoringService" behaviorConfiguration="behavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="tcpbinding" contract="MonitoringServer.IMonitoringService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:54322/Monitoring" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="tcpbinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Client A app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning,ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="c:\dev\monitoring\monitoring_new\client\monitoringclient\app_messages.svclog"
        type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WebServiceAddress" value="net.tcp://localhost:54322/Monitoring"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors />
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IMonitoringService" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
          openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
          hostNameComparisonMode="WeakWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          portSharingEnabled="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession enabled="true" />
          <security mode="Message" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:54322/Monitoring" binding="netTcpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IMonitoringService" contract="MonitoringServiceReference.IMonitoringService"
        name="NetTcpBinding_IMonitoringService">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="DEV-JC-18\panipro" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Client "B" app.config

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WebServiceAddress" value="net.tcp://localhost:54322/Monitoring"/>
  </appSettings>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
              <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IMonitoringService" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
                  receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
              </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:54322/Monitoring" binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IMonitoringService" contract="MonitoringServiceReference.IMonitoringService"
                name="NetTcpBinding_IMonitoringService">
                <identity>
                    <userPrincipalName value="DEV-JC-18\panipro" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Can someone just point out what I'm doing wrong ?
Thank's in advance.

Comment: When do you get the message and where? Can you start the services from a standalone app for easier debugging?

Comment: try with missing attributes <binding name="tcpbinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  transferMode="Buffered" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" etc/>.May be by default the buffer size is limited.

Comment: @Sentry, I have a Windows Form interface where the web service is installed that allows me to communicate with the clients. I have a button to recover the content of a file of the different clients and I get the message when i press it. it happens on the client "b" side.